# ComboBox does not refresh, when data changes in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh, jcombobox

I'm trying to develop a little application in which there's a JComboBox that is initialized at start with some elements, retrieved from JTable. The JTable will constantly be changing, due to different data being inserted.

However, whenever I insert new data to the database or remove it, the combobox does not update, only when I close the program and open it.
Could anyone give me a hint/ help of what I am doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
private void fillcombopart() {

        try {
            String sql = "select * from partrepair";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\database.db");
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
             DefaultComboBoxModel model12 = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

             while (rs.next()) {

     model12.addElement(rs.getString("Name"));
    model12.addListDataListener(partCombo);
} 
partCombo.setModel(model12);
               // partCombo.addItem(rs.getString("Name"));


            pst.close();
            rs.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

update method for databse

```
public void refresh2() {
        try {
            String sql12 = "select * from partrepair";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(s);
            PreparedStatement pst12 = conn.prepareStatement(sql12);
            ResultSet rs = pst12.executeQuery();
            tablerepair.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            pst12.close();
            rs.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not many database provide mechanisms for listening for changes.  You best bet is to either provide a means by which you can either automatically or manually check with the database and update the contents of combobox accordingly...

Comment: ive got an update method for my jtable, which will update the jtable when database has been changed

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever i insert new data to the database or remove it, the combobox does not update, only when i close the program and open it. Could anyone give me a hint/ help of what i am doing wrong.

You only appear to set the JComboBox's model once and never update it after that, or if you do, you don't show us. The model won't change by magic -- you have to write code to change it if the database's data changes. This means that you will have to somehow listen for changes to the database, and then when this occurs, update your JComboBox's model.

Comment: i added  model12.addListDataListener(partCombo);, which should listen to the change, but how would i update it

Comment: @jayd: that confused me -- that is asking the JComboBox's model to listen to the same JComboBox -- doesn't make sense and certainly will receive no notification from the database re change.  You could look into using [Beans-Binding](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html).

Comment: is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you check your database only once. Try to use separated thread.